# Why does tf.data.Dataset.sample_from_datasets() gets unknown length from input of known length?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Here a simple MWE :

```
list(tf.data.Dataset.sample_from_datasets((tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([1,2,3]), tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors(42).repeat(4))))
```

returns :

```
[<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=1>,
 <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=42>,
 <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=2>,
 <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=3>,
 <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=42>,
 <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=42>,
 <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=42>]
```

But when doing :

```
len(tf.data.Dataset.sample_from_datasets((tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([1,2,3]), tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors(42).repeat(4))))
```

I get an error :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[17], line 1
----> 1 len(tf.data.Dataset.sample_from_datasets((tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([1,2,3]), tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors(42).repeat(4))))

File /usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py:532, in DatasetV2.__len__(self)
    530   raise TypeError("The dataset is infinite.")
    531 if length.numpy() == UNKNOWN:
--> 532   raise TypeError("The dataset length is unknown.")
    533 return length

TypeError: The dataset length is unknown.
```

Why is the length of `sample_from_datasets` not known while it's prefectly previsible to be `sum(len(d) for d in datasets)` ?

The only edge case would be when :

- if `any(d.cardinality() == tf.data.INFINITE_CARDINALITY for d in dataset)` then, the length is infinite
- if `any(d.cardinality() == tf.data.UNKOWN_CARDINALITY for d in dataset) or stop_on_empty_dataset` then length is unkown